# Assign jQuery ajaxStart/ajaxStop to specific links only

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery that shows/hides div `#loading` with a spinner inside of it depending on `.ajaxStart` or `.ajaxStop`. However it seems too general. Other links I click - or forms I try and submit - trigger the spinner. So is there a way to limit the code below to apply only to the links in my `ul#infoContainer`?

```
$(function() {
    $('#loading')
        .hide() // hide initially
        .ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxStop(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Global Ajax events are just that, global.

If you want to attach the behavior just to `$("ul#infoContainer a")` then it might be better off using a click handler that does `#loading` show/hide.

Alternately, you could set `global: false` in the Ajax requests you *don't* want to trigger the global behavior. To me it makes more sense to explicitly define the behavior where I want rather than disable it where I don't, but that's just bias on my part.